# Why is Asp.net core identity add migration is first dropping table and creating again

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am adding a field in Asp.Net Core Identity

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Permissions { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i add migration it first drop tables then add column and at the end it recreate tables. But i have some references in other tables so i don't want to delete AspNetUser table

[image]

I added the migration and class is created

[image]

When i update database

```
update-database -Context ApplicationDbContext
```

then error is occured

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Comment: It's probably not connecting to the database, check your connectionstring

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I created a new asp.net core 2.2 with Identity, and add new `ApplicationUser`, command `add-migration` and `update-database` works correctly.

Comment: Connection string is in appsetting.json and working perfectly. And i have multiple context so i a, doing with context name.

Comment: What is the detail steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I did not add any migration on the Asp.Net Identity so all tables and names are same when project is created. So i need to add a column named as 'Permissions' so i added in ApplicationUser class. After that i add a simple migration through add-migration AddPermission -ContextApplicationDbContext. context is defined because i am also using db first approach and have another context. When i try to call update-database it said tables is already define in database

Comment: I also use update-database AddPermission -Context ApplicationDbContext. but it is giving me same error. After that i update the class which is generated through migration and remove all CreateIndex and DropIndex code, but it is also giving me the same error.